# How to customize an invoice (using the Sylius invoicing plugin)?

Tags: plugins, customization, sylius, invoice

I followed the sylius doc to customize the pdf invoice generated when the order is onfirmed by the user, as I need to change the sylius log with the client's logo, but nothing is working... I am a beginner so it might just be a basic problem, but all my attempts to find what is wrong on the internet have failed, so can anyone help to put me on the right path? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here:
https://github.com/Sylius/InvoicingPlugin/blob/master/src/Resources/config/services.xml#L10

So you should set the env variable SYLIUS_INVOICING_LOGO_FILE that contains the path to your logo.